# Error aligning divs in a responsive webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the alignment of two divs. I'm using bootstrap for a responsive page.

[This is the image on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZHk5.jpg)

[This is the image on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiBbK.jpg)

It's like the image isn't adjusting itself with the container div and just staying in the original position.

this is the HTML code:

```
     <div class="Guy">
         <div  class="img_guy">
            <img src="./images/profile1.png" class="img-circle img-responsive">
       </div>

            <div  class="Content">
            <h1 class="tagline">JAMES H. MAYER, ESQ.</h1>
             <br> 
            <h2 class="tagline">San Diego's "Top Lawyers" (Mediation)</h2>
            <h2 class="tagline">San Diego Magazine 2012-2015" (Mediation)</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
    .Guy {
    margin:  2% auto;
    float:left;
      max-width: 800px;
      overflow:hidden;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
      border-radius: 112px;
    }

    .img_guy {
     float:left;
      width:40%;
      height:64%;  
    }

    .Content {
         float:left;
         width: 45%;
         height:60%;
    }

    .Content h1 {
      color: #E4A500;
       font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 100%;
    }

    .Content h2 {
      color: #e1e8f0;
       font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 90%;
    }
```

Any hint that may be causing this?

Comment: I don't see any bootstrap classes in your HTML. Why is that?

Comment: I needed to modify some because It didn't have what I needed, for example  the yellow letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how this could be done so it keeps a highly responsive nature from mobile up.

See example Snippet at Full page then reduce your browser.

```css
#guy {
  background: url('http://www.getitdonecleaning.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/office-cleaning-fife.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}
.people-list {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 112px;
}
.profile,
.details {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}
.details h2 {
  color: #E4A500;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.details h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .profile img {
    height: 150px;
  }
  .people-list {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .profile,
  .details {
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
  .details h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
  }
  .details h3 {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .people-list {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .profile,
  .details {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron" id="guy">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Some other Title Here</h1>

    <div class="people-list">
      <div class="profile">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class="img-circle" />
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <h2>JAMES H. MAYER, ESQ.</h2>

        <h3>San Diego's "Top Lawyers" (Mediation)</h3>

        <h3>San Diego Magazine 2012-2015" (Mediation)</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Update

As far as the structure goes: using a jumbotron in this instance makes sense since you're using Bootstrap (it takes care of your H1 and background for the most part), then placing all your elements inside a div to create a space for your image and text (`.people-list`) so you can set margin/padding/width etc independently of the objects enclosed within.

For the image/text inside using `display:table-cell` will do just that, it will treat those elements like s along with `vertical-align` so everything is centered inside your main div.

The rest comes down to using media queries to adjust all the sizes to your image/text isn't crushed together and remains readable and user friendly.
(**Note**: I also took the chance to refactor this somewhat as I had some duplicate/unnecessary rules.)

***Sidenote***: Why I changed the display to block under 360px. There are many devices (namely iPhone 4/5) that have a CSS width of 320px. Trying to display the image and text side-by-side on a small screen isn't ideal for many reasons.

*See image and Example Snippet by re-sizing your browser. And test on actual devises, this can't be stressed enough.

[image]

**Unchanged display property**: to be viewed down to 320px (*You may need to use Firefox if you use a desktop)

And please note, there is no `display: row` property: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
#guy {
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
}
.people-list {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 112px;
}
.profile,
.details {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}
.details h2 {
  color: #E4A500;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.details h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #guy {
    background: teal;
  }
  .profile img {
    height: 150px;
  }
  .people-list {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .profile,
  .details {
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
  .details h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
  }
  .details h3 {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  #guy {
    background: lightblue;
  }
  .people-list {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  #guy {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron" id="guy">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Some other Title Here</h1>

    <div class="people-list">
      <div class="profile">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" class="img-circle" />
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <h2>JAMES H. MAYER, ESQ.</h2>

        <h3>San Diego's "Top Lawyers" (Mediation)</h3>

        <h3>San Diego Magazine 2012-2015" (Mediation)</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, I modified something, there was an error in screen with max-width :360, the photo didn't align right, just change display:block to display:row.
Good job vanburen, if it is not much troublesome, could you explain some of your code?